# Can't get fwrite to store wstring's

Tags: c++

I'm trying to store a structure containing a `wstring` (`Struct2`) to disk but it doesn't work (stores garbage) yet if I change `wstring` to `wchar_t` (`Struct1`) it works.

```
struct Struct1
{
    bool mFoo;
    wchar_t mBar[64];
};

struct Struct2
{
    bool mFoo;
    wstring mBar;
};
```

I've tried `fwrite`, `ofstream`, etc but all seem to behave the same when dealing with wide characters. I would just like to know why `wchar_t` works and `wstring` doesn't when they're essentially the same type.

Comment: Let's see how you're writing `Struct2` to a file.  My crystal ball is telling me that this is yet another "binary file writing" mishap.

Comment: Also, if you are using `fwrite`, and if you are using `sizeof(Struct2)` as one of the arguments, then this could never work if you realize what that argument to `fwrite` means.  Assume that `wstring` had 1000 characters in it.  The `sizeof(Struct2)` is a compile-time constant, maybe it's 32 bytes, 40 bytes, whatever.  So how is `fwrite` going to write more than 1000 bytes if the argument is only 32 or 40 bytes?  Ergo, the call to `fwrite` was never going to work.

Comment: If I use fwrite(&mStruct1, sizeof(Struct), 1, mFileOut); the contents of mBar is stored. If I use the same for Struct2 then I get garbage even if I resize mBar to 64. Is it possible to write a struct to disk or do I have to store the individual variables to make sure I store the wstring length correctly?

Comment: Well, of course it will not work, as explained in the comment.  You have to actually write the data, not the "struct".  That means taking each item, and individually saving it to the file in a coherent, consistent manner, so that you can read it back and recreate the object.  What you are looking for is object *serialization*.

Comment: OK thanks Paul, I suspected that saving a struct wouldn't work but was thrown by Struct1 working but I now know that it only worked as the data was small < 10 bytes.

Comment: More than likely, the data was stored in an array, due to small string optimization.  Thus it seemed to work for small data.  But increase that to 50 characters, 100 characters, etc. you will see the code collapse, as `sizeof(Struct2)` would be stuck on 40 (or so) bytes, while the actual data you want to save is hundreds, maybe thousands of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably doing something like this:

```
fwrite(&s, sizeof(s), 1, file);
```

That won't work for serializing the wstring member to disk. At best, it will just write out the pointer address and other internals of that string class to disk.

`ofstream` doesn't know about wide-char.  But [std::wofstream](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/wofstream/) does.  Make sure you use the [binary](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/openmode/) flag when opening the file for writing since you are mixing characters and non-character data into the same file.